# Setting JWT authentication in Kibana Opendistro

Tags: jwt, kibana, elasticsearch-opendistro

I am trying to set up JWT authentication for Kibana in Opendistro 1.13.1, which is running on Docker. My docker-compose.yml file is:

```
version: '3'
services:
  odfe-node1:
image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:1.13.1
container_name: odfe-node1
environment:
  - cluster.name=odfe-cluster
  - node.name=odfe-node1
  - discovery.seed_hosts=odfe-node1,odfe-node2
  - cluster.initial_master_nodes=odfe-node1,odfe-node2
  - bootstrap.memory_lock=true # along with the memlock settings below, disables swapping
  - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" # minimum and maximum Java heap size, recommend setting both to 50% of system RAM
ulimits:
  memlock:
    soft: -1
    hard: -1
  nofile:
    soft: 65536 # maximum number of open files for the Elasticsearch user, set to at least 65536 on modern systems
    hard: 65536
volumes:
  - odfe-data1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  - ./config.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/config.yml
ports:
  - 9200:9200
  - 9600:9600 # required for Performance Analyzer
networks:
  - odfe-net
odfe-node2:
  image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:1.13.1
  container_name: odfe-node2
  environment:
    - cluster.name=odfe-cluster
    - node.name=odfe-node2
    - discovery.seed_hosts=odfe-node1,odfe-node2
    - cluster.initial_master_nodes=odfe-node1,odfe-node2
    - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
    - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
ulimits:
  memlock:
    soft: -1
    hard: -1
  nofile:
    soft: 65536
    hard: 65536
volumes:
  - odfe-data2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  - ./config.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/config.yml
networks:
  - odfe-net
kibana:
  image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch-kibana:1.13.1
  container_name: odfe-kibana
  ports:
    - 5601:5601
  expose:
    - "5601"
  volumes:
    - ./kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
  environment:
    ELASTICSEARCH_URL: https://odfe-node1:9200
    ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: https://odfe-node1:9200
  networks:
    - odfe-net

volumes:
  odfe-data1:
  odfe-data2:

networks:
  odfe-net:
```

My config.yml file contains the following section:

```
 jwt_auth_domain:
    enabled: true
    http_enabled: true
    transport_enabled: true
    order: 0
    http_authenticator:
      type: jwt
      challenge: false
      config:
        signing_key: "oeRaYY7Wo24sDqKSX3IM9ASGmdGPmkTd9jo1QTy4b7P9Ze5_9hKolVX8xNrQDcNRfVEdTZNOuOyqEGhXEbdJI-ZQ19k_o9MI0y3eZN2lp9jow55FfXMiINEdt1XR85VipRLSOkT6kSpzs2x-jbLDiz9iFVzkd81YKxMgPA7VfZeQUm4n-mOmnWMaVX30zGFU4L3oPBctYKkl4dYfqY>
        jwt_header: "Authorization"
        jwt_url_parameter: null
        roles_key: "roles"
        subject_key: "sub"
      authentication_backend:
        type: noop
```

The kibana.yml is:

```
server.name: kibana
server.host: "0"
elasticsearch.hosts: https://localhost:9200
elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: none
elasticsearch.username: kibanaserver
elasticsearch.password: kibanaserver
elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: ["securitytenant","Authorization"]

opendistro_security.multitenancy.enabled: true
opendistro_security.multitenancy.tenants.preferred: ["Private", "Global"]
opendistro_security.readonly_mode.roles: ["kibana_read_only"]
opendistro_security.auth.type: "jwt"

opendistro_security.cookie.secure: false

newsfeed.enabled: false
telemetry.optIn: false
telemetry.enabled: false
security.showInsecureClusterWarning: false
```

Finally, I executed a GET request to my client on Postman after generating a valid authentication token:

```
{
"info": {
    "_postman_id": "7bb92352-26c3-4e1d-b64a-c312b5cea23a",
    "name": "kibana",
    "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
},
"item": [
    {
        "name": "test",
        "request": {
            "auth": {
                "type": "oauth2",
                "oauth2": [
                    {
                        "key": "clientSecret",
                        "value": "2da2cec1-a347-4d9d-8060-86176d28c162",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "tokenType",
                        "value": "Bearer",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "accessToken",
                        "value": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJDczhvVkJrVFRnR2NGdHNzQzE3V19DRVFUQzNPSjhwSy1oS1ppMGNHNHFVIn0.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.du_i-IXhReYGzUzKJ2jNto5jBl75pA9ShZ968DjpggK9CT8DUMVm6lCwqYo38h231ouPtALGj1Lpk_YWy7HZKX5gmZvfredIwPZw7TEeMHbw2Q_B7uu8zPrD6Be6oLmcogbchMWG9CxNwrUdN1igqnZ6OWl-6l7RQCpb8KPvzCugnzwwyk6fXpNsWSDm9HliHC66FVb-6evYdB1V_xWrCZoUvMVLIG3G0W7ojdTjVEX_t8EgvMNwZeIcyzDY1kjvJhr7ORRX8SYi0mxJQgZuqHrSV63ssWpzUXvK9BSlgEbMfMJSIqZdVDzQil7eg3IKVv6CziEk0L08-6gGSg66cg",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "accessTokenUrl",
                        "value": "http://10.10.252.84/auth/realms/kibana/protocol/openid-connect/token",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "password",
                        "value": "admin",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "username",
                        "value": "admin",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "clientId",
                        "value": "kibana-jwt",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "tokenName",
                        "value": "Kibana Token",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "scope",
                        "value": "openid",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "grant_type",
                        "value": "password_credentials",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "addTokenTo",
                        "value": "header",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "method": "GET",
            "header": [],
            "url": {
                "raw": "http://10.10.252.102:5601",
                "protocol": "http",
                "host": [
                    "10",
                    "10",
                    "252",
                    "102"
                ],
                "port": "5601"
            }
        },
        "response": []
    }
]
}
```

The response to this was the following error message:

```
{
"statusCode": 401,
"error": "Unauthorized",
"message": "Authorization error"
}
```

Can anyone figure out what I have been doing wrong?

Comment: I am observing the same behavior. It seems there was an outstanding issue - https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/security-kibana-plugin/issues/687

But url is moved

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding token as a url param? By adding below to your kibana.yml

```
opendistro_security.jwt.url_param: jwttoken
```

and then  try accessing kibana like http://localhost:5601/jwttoken=<your_jwt>

Even you can try the below config in your kibana.yml (as below config is working for me)

```
server.name: kibana
server.port: 5601
server.host: "127.0.0.1"

elasticsearch.url: https://127.0.0.1:9200
elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: none
elasticsearch.username: kibanaserver
elasticsearch.password: kibanaserver
elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: ["securitytenant","Authorization"]

opendistro_security.auth.type: "jwt"
opendistro_security.jwt.url_param: jwttoken

opendistro_security.multitenancy.enabled: true
opendistro_security.multitenancy.tenants.preferred: ["Private", "Global"]
opendistro_security.readonly_mode.roles: ["kibana_read_only"]
....
```

Also Please make sure that you are running security-admin.sh each time you are updating something in your config.yml , otherwise security index will not be picking up the new changes.

Edit :
Also , from opendistro 7 security , I noticed that we don't need enabled:true as part of jwt config in config.yml file.